# How can I pass an event from one class to a child object?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, overriding

I have a class called `TextBoxPlus` that inherits from `UserControl` and holds multiple regular `TextBox` instances, while also exapnding on their functionality. I have an instace of `TextBoxPlus` in my Windows Form that is calling the `TextChanged` event. The issue I have is I want it to pass through to the `TextChanged` event of one of the `TextBox` instances within the `TextBoxPlus`. I don't want to make the `TextBox` public so I'm likely looking at an `override` but I'm not sure on how to do this as this does not work:

```
protected override void TextChanged(EventArgs e)
{
    this.textbox.TextChanged(e);
}
```

obviously due to the `TextChanged` event not calling a method. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried to add an event handler to each individual text box when you add it to your user control?  tb.OnTextChanged += new...

Comment: You need to handle the `TextChanged` events of each textbox and raise the `TextChanged` event of `TextBoxPlus`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define an event on the containing class whose implementation adds its handlers to the contained object's events:

```
public event  EventHandler TextChanged
{
    add
    {
        textbox.TextChanged += value;
    }
    remove
    {
        textbox.TextChanged -= value;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great, I didn't know about add and remove attributes for event handlers. Thank you so much!